# puting component inside return in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, function, jsx

I'm a beginner on `React.js` and I'm a little bit confused with components in React, can we just put a component's code in return instead of making component,  here I have (simple todo list) two codes first one is working correctly but the second one I have changed it a little bit but it's not working, or I'm doing it wrong?

**Here is 1:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Todo({ tod, index }) {
  return <div className="todo">{tod.text}</div>
}

function TodoForm({ addTodo }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');



  return (

    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Add Todo..."
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}

      />

    </form>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ]);

  const addTodo = text => {
    const newTodos = [...todos, { text }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="todo-List">
        {todos.map((todo, index) =>
          <Todo key={index} index={index} tod={todo} />
        )}
        <TodoForm addTodo={addTodo} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

**And here is how I changed that code by taking everything from function TodoForm and put it in return 2:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Todo({ tod, index }) {
  return <div className="todo">{tod.text}</div>
}


const [value, setValue] = useState('');





function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ]);

  const addTodo = text => {
    const newTodos = [...todos, { text }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="todo-List">
        {todos.map((todo, index) =>
          <Todo key={index} index={index} tod={todo} />
        )}

        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="input"
            value={value}
            placeholder="Add Todo..."
            onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}

          />

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

I want the second code to work like the first one so I deleted component and put its codes in return.
Here is an error I'm getting:

```
react.development.js:1465 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: Could you please format the code you provided a little? Also, I am not sure what exactly your question is.

Comment: Please tell us *how* it is "not working"

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `const [value, setValue] = useState('');` inside App function:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, yes, you can extract components into functions.

As far as why it is not working, you would have to be a little more specific on *what* exactly is not working.

You can format your code like so:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Todo({ text, index }) {
  return <div className="todo">{text}</div>
}

function TodoForm({ addTodo }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(''); // what is `addTodo` used for? maybe you do not need `value`
 
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Add Todo..."
        onChange={e => addTodo(e.target.value)}

      />
    </form>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: ' Learn about react',
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ]);

  const addTodo = text => {
    const newTodos = [...todos, { text }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="todo-List">
        {todos.map((todo, index) =>
          <Todo key={index} index={index} text={todo.text} />
        )}
        <TodoForm addTodo={addTodo} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Something else you can do is:

```
const Todo = ({ text, index }) => (
  return <div className="todo">{text}</div>
)

const TodoForm = ({ addTodo }) => (
    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Add Todo..."
        onChange={e => addTodo(e.target.value)}

      />
    </form>
)
```